# Laravel 5.1 commands and jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

So, as far as I understand, commands are now jobs in Laravel 5.1. If I'd like to schedule a job, should I call a job from a command then (since the scheduler can only call commands and not jobs)?

In the dummy setup of Laravel 5.1 there still is a app/Console/Commands folder with Inspire.php in it. The inspire command is called from the scheduler. So if I'd like to schedule a job, should I call a command and then call the job inside this command?

Answer (score 0):

Commands are not jobs. Commands are commands - you can create them and use them via command line. They can, however, be used for scheduling repeated tasks.

In this case - if you need a "job" - the documentation states:

> The only Cron entry you need to add to your server is this:
>
> - - - - - php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

After you did that, you are free to use the implementation explained **[here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands)**. Basically, you use the Scheduler to set tasks that will run in whatever iterations you like. Pretty cool, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if you'd like to call a "(queue) job" from the scheduler you have to do that via a command?