# Laravel commands and jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jobs, laravel-5.1

I was wondering what the difference is between the different command-like classes in Laravel 5.1. As far as I can tell Laravel 5.1 has the following available:

- Console commands (`artisan make:console`)
- Commands (`artisan make:command`)

  - Handlers (`artisan make::command --handler`)
- Jobs (`artisan make:job`)

I have come straight from 4.2 to 5.1 so I don't know what happened in between 4.2 and 5.1, but I have been told that the middle one (*just* commands) are basically not really supposed to be used any more - they are in from when queue-able jobs became 'commands' in 5.0, but Laravel since decided against this, and they're just in for compatibility. However, I'm not 100% on this point, so clarification would be appreciated.

My specific use-case is that I want a place to put a self-contained 'runnable' task. For example, something that will remove files older than 5 days from a given directory (but it could do anything).

At first this sounds like a console command - I want to be able to run it from `artisan`, for a start. But I may also want it on a schedule (great, `artisan schedule:run` runs console commands). But I may also want to execute it asynchronously from code. Console commands can be run *synchronously* with `Artisan::call()`, but for asynchronous, this is (I think) where queues come in, and it suddenly has to be a job.

Okay so we have a job. We can now add it to a queue from code, but how do we execute it as an artisan command (synchronously)? Can I just create a thin console command and add the `DispatchesJobs` trait (or the code therein) to it, and then dispatch the job? Does the job always have to go on a queue, or can we make a job execute synchronously (and, ideally, output to the console command's output?) The same question goes for running it on a schedule - am I supposed to create this console command and add that to the scheduler, or can I make the scheduler run the job directly?

And finally, we have 'commands' that aren't console commands nor are they jobs. As I said before, people tell me these are just hangers-on from a Laravel 5.0 code change that was (kinda) reverted. But the `artisan make` command still exists for them, so they can't be *that* dead. Also, what's the deal with a self handling command (the default, comes with a `handle` method) and one that 'requires' a handler class (run `artisan make:command --handler`)? How do you actually make these execute? Manually with `(new App\Command\SomeCommand)->handle();` or `(new App\handlers\SomeCommandHandler)->handle(new App\Command\SomeCommand)`, or is there some hidden system I don't know about (maybe they can be dispatched using the job/queue dispatcher)? Also you can create 'queued' commands `artisan make::command --queued`, so how do these differ, too?

I guess my question boils down to the following:

- What is the real (semantic **and** functional) difference between them all?
- What is the correct way to 'run' them?
- Which is best for my purposes of a generally-standalone bit of code that needs to be run, in whatever manner I feel appropriate?

I found information in the documentation on how to use queues and create console commands, but nothing on exactly when to use them or really anything on command classes and handlers.

---

Related but not exactly the same (also, it's unanswered): [Laravel 5.1 commands and jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995183/laravel-5-1-commands-and-jobs)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see those "objects" like so: (I added some code examples from one of my side projects)

#### Console

Things I want to execute from the command line (As you mentioned with your example with "Delete Files older than x"). But the thing is, you could extract the business logic of it to a **command**.

[Example](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/imgubox/blob/master/app/Console/Commands/FetchUserFavs.php#L57): A console command with fires a command to fetch images from Imgur. The Class `FetchImages`  contains the actual business logic of fetching images.

#### Command

Class which contains the actual logic. You should also be able to call this command from your application with `app()->make(Command::class)->handle()`.

[Example](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/imgubox/blob/master/app/Jobs/FetchImages.php): Command mentioned in Example 1. Contains logic which does the actual API calls to Imgur and process returned data.

#### Jobs

I made this app with Laravel 5.0 so `jobs` weren't a thing back then. But as I see it, Jobs are like commands but they are queued and can be dispatched. (As you may have seen in those examples, those commands implement your mentioned Interfaces `SelfHandling` and `ShouldBeQueued`).

---

I see myself as an experienced Laravel Developer but those changes in `Commands` and `Jobs` are quite difficult to understand.

EDIT:
From the Laravel Docs:

> The app/Commands directory has been renamed to app/Jobs. However, you are not required to move all of your commands to the new location, and you may continue using the make:command and handler:command Artisan commands to generate your classes.
>
> Likewise, the app/Handlers directory has been renamed to app/Listeners and now only contains event listeners. However, you are not required to move or rename your existing command and event handlers, and you may continue to use the handler:event command to generate event handlers.
>
> By providing backwards compatibility for the Laravel 5.0 folder structure, you may upgrade your applications to Laravel 5.1 and slowly upgrade your events and commands to their new locations when it is convenient for you or your team.

Answer (score 30):

### Console Commands

Laravel has had console "commands" for some time. They are basically unchanged, and work as they always have. In simple terms, they are the equivalent of routes for the command line - the entry point into the application. They are in no way related to...

### The Command Bus

Laravel 5.0 introduced an implementation of the `Command Bus` pattern - Command Bus Commands. (I believe these were renamed to Jobs because of the resulting confusion between them and CLI Commands).

A command bus as two parts - an object that represents a command to be executed, with any and all data it needs (the job), and a class to execute the command (the handler).

### The Handler

In laravel, you can declare a job to be self handling - that is, it has a handle method itself.

If you want to register a command handler, you can call the following in a service provider:

```
app('Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher')->maps(['Job' => 'Handler']);
```

where Job is the class name for the job, and Handler is the class name for the handler.

The handlers directory in laravel 5.0 was a way of implicitly declaring those relationships (ie. `EmailCommand` in the commands folder would have an `EmailCommandHandler` in the handlers folder).

### Dispatching a Command

You can use the following to dispatch a command.

```
app('Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher')->dispatch(new EmailPersonCommand('email@you.com', $otherdata));
```

### Queues

Jobs, by default, will run as soon as they are called (or dispatched). Setting them as `ShouldQueue` will always pass them to a queue when they are dispatched.

If you want to run them synchronously sometimes, and asynchronously other times, you can call `$dispatcher->dispatchToQueue($job)` when you want them to be queued. This is all that happens internally when you pass a `ShouldQueue` job to `->dispatch()`.

### edit: To Queuing (or not)

I've just had a longer look at the dispatcher. The `dispatch` method checks if the command is a `ShouldQueue`, and either forwards it to `dispatchToQueue` or `dispatchNow`. You can call either of those methods directly instead of `dispatch` with your command should you wish to override the default behaviour.

So in your case, depending on what the "default" behaviour of your job is (ie. will it normally be queued?) either:
- have it `ShouldQueue`, and use `dispatchNow` in the CLI Command.
- don't have it `ShouldQueue`, and use `dispatchToQueue` where you call it in your code.

From the sounds of it, i'd do the former.

Comment: So if I write a job that can be queued but doesn't have to be queued, I should not have `ShouldQueue` interface, as it will make my job *always* queue, even though I don't *always* what that? But I *can* still queue a job that doesn't have `ShouldQueue`, right?

Comment: @alexrussell - i've just edited my answer after looking into it a bit more.

Comment: A-ha that makes sense. I'd looked into the dispatcher myself and found `dispatchNow` which I am indeed using in my console command, but I didn't realise I could invert this behaviour. Thanks for this, it's been very helpful.

Comment: FYI I have accepted @stefanzweifel's answer as it more closely answers the question asked (what are they all and what's the deal with 5.0/5.1), also I did continue the discussion a little with him in Slack and got a bit more clarity (or at the very least a bit of "yes it's very confusing, it's not just you!"). However, your explanation here of the 5.0 command bus stuff was really helpful to my specific situation and if I could accept both I would!

Comment: ha - yeah. i did get a bit sidetracked from the actual question! :) glad i could help!

Comment: I was looking for your last paragraph, happy to find it :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to the actual answers.

**Jobs in Laravel >= 5.1 are Commands Bus in Laravel 5.0**.

It is only a naming change because of the confusion between `Console\Commands` (commands run from the console) and The `Command Bus` (containing `Commands`) for the Application Tasks.

You should not confound :

- `Command Bus` : used for "encapsulating tasks your application" (from laravel 5.0 doc) which is now renamed a `Jobs`
- `Console\Commands` : used for "Artisan [...] the command-line interface included with Laravel" (from laravel 5.1 docs) which is unchanged in Laravel since 4.x

Comment: Just seems odd that 5.1 has both commands and jobs, then, and that they work as two separate things.

Comment: I updated my answer for more precision about `Command Bus` != `Console Commands`

Comment: Sory @Ifnot, I do now understand the whole situation - it's just interesting how commands were 'renamed' to jobs, but weren't actually renamed in terms of the Laravel framework code: 5.1 has console commands yes but then it has *both* commands (as in bus) *and* jobs (as in the 'new' commands). You'd imagine if it was a simple rename, then 5.1 wouldn't have both commands and jobs. Anyway, I understand it's for BC reasons - Taylor wanted 5.0 people to be able to easily upgrade to 5.1, so left the command bus as-is, but introduced jobs as the successor to commands. Hence having both available.

Comment: @alexrussell Yes, `Command Bus` stay compatible from 5.0 to 5.1 for avoiding BC but is not documented anymore as the `Jobs` should replace the mechanism.

Comment: Indeed - I think my initial confusion came from the fact that the commands weren't marked as deprecated in artisan nor was there any documentation to suggest that jobs had taken over commands in 5.1.

Comment: My confusion would be the opposite - that jobs weren't marked as deprecated as no we are in 5.6 v