# Laravel difference between command and jobs

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to understand what are the differences between **jobs** and **commands**.

I was reading the documentation and it seems that both jobs and commands have similar structure and both of the can be scheduled with the difference that jobs can also be queued.

And i was wondering if the only difference is that jobs can be queued, because it seems to me that they have overlap functionalities.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095167/laravel-commands-and-jobs
It's a possible answer to your problem

Comment: i did read that it didn't help me to understand the differences

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we use the command to execute a particular function or a job at a particular time or frequency. And we can call command via terminal. But the job cannot be called via terminal. Jobs can be queued. Also, you can execute Job at a particular time. But it is not a repetitive event.